# Combine values from different rows into one row only when there is only one value in each column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe called "rawfile" as below.

```
structure(list(mz = c(123, 243, 277, 456, 886.555, 886.556, 887.565, 
887.567, 887.568), condition.1 = c(0.001, 0.003, 2e-04, NA, 0.000511135, 
NA, NA, 0.000162055, NA), condition.2 = c(NA, NA, 3e-04, 0.007, 
NA, 0.000661594, 1e-04, 3e-04, NA), condition.3 = c(NA, NA, 4e-04, 
NA, NA, 0.000502741, NA, NA, 2e-04), group = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
5, 6, 6, 6)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to move all the values to the top row within each group if there is more than one row present in one group.
I used the following code and it works if there is only one value within each column in one group.

```
# Function to move all values to the top row based on group
move_values <- function(df) {
  if (nrow(df) > 1) {
    for (col in grep("^condition", names(df), value = TRUE)) {
      df[1, col] <- ifelse(any(!is.na(df[, col])), df[!is.na(df[, col]), col], NA)
      df[-1, col] <- NA  # Fill other rows with NA for the current column
    }
  }
  return(df)
}

# Group the data by 'group' and apply the move_values function
result <- rawfile %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  do(move_values(.)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

However, for this dataframe, there is more than one value in the same column (condition 2) in group 6, and I want to keep this group unchanged if this happens.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to filter out groups with more than one values in the same column? And move the values to the top row for other groups?

The expected dataframe I would like to have in the end is below:

```
structure(list(mz = c(123, 243, 277, 456, 886.555, 886.556, 887.565, 
887.567, 887.568), condition.1 = c(0.001, 0.003, 2e-04, NA, 0.000511135, 
NA, NA, 0.000162055, NA), condition.2 = c(NA, NA, 3e-04, 0.007, 
0.000661594, NA, 1e-04, 3e-04, NA), condition.3 = c(NA, NA, 4e-04, 
NA, 0.000502741, NA, NA, NA, 2e-04), group = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: Seems you are looking for  `mutate(df, group = consecutive_id(round(mz, 2)))`. Nothing about moving anything anywhere

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I updated the expected outcome. In the expected table, all the values from group 5 are move to the top row in group 5, but not group 6 because there are more than one values in the same column in group 6. However, the move_values function does not work for me if there are more than two values in the same column in the same group

Comment: I made a function "move_values" to move the value from the same group to the top row but that only works if there is only one value in each column within a group

Comment: The groups are already defined in the original dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You can create the `cond`ition with by `sum`ming the `complete.cases` `across` the selected columns, and then use this `cond`ition in an `ifelse` statement, and sort complete and incomplete cases.

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(cond = rowSums(across(condition.1:condition.3, \(x) sum(complete.cases(x))) > 1),
         across(condition.1:condition.3, \(x) ifelse(cond == 0, c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)]), x)),
         .by = group)

#        mz condition.1 condition.2 condition.3 group cond
# 1 123.000 0.001000000          NA          NA     1    0
# 2 243.000 0.003000000          NA          NA     2    0
# 3 277.000 0.000200000 0.000300000 0.000400000     3    0
# 4 456.000          NA 0.007000000          NA     4    0
# 5 886.555 0.000511135 0.000661594 0.000502741     5    0
# 6 886.556          NA          NA          NA     5    0
# 7 887.565          NA 0.000100000          NA     6    1
# 8 887.567 0.000162055 0.000300000          NA     6    1
# 9 887.568          NA          NA 0.000200000     6    1
```